# Query giving only one result

Tags: c#, sql

My query is giving one result only i.e. one word for one URL when it should run for every entry in `dt`. Here `dt` is `DataTable` and contains many rows, `url_given` is a String. `temp` is table containing the words to be matched. Can anybody please tell me what is wrong with my query?
`wordcount` is the name of the table. `url_String`, `word` and `count` are columns.

> The purpose of the query is to get the URLs matched with given URL and
>   their words which are in the list which is `temp`.

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
     // read item
     url_given = row["url_String"].ToString();
     String qrystring = "select url_String,word,count from wordcount where url_String='" + url_given + "' and word in (select * from temp) ";
     dt1 = db.searchandorder(qrystring);
     // searchandorder is a call to a function that establishes the db connections and passes the query to the data adapter.
 }
```

Here is my `searchandorder` function:

```
public DataTable searchandorder (String sql)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill( dt);
    conn.Close();
    Console.Write("table coloumns" + dt.Columns.ToString());
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: No details of db.SearchAndOrder and no Samples of how the rows will be..???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact you loop overwriting `dt1` every time. You need to merge the results not replace them, but I can't say how you would do that without seeing `db.searchandorder`.

Also you have a very dangerous sql injection attack. If `url_given` was `'; drop table wordcount; --` what would be the query the program will execute on the server? You need to use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with your data adapter.

EDIT: So, now that you shown your code, here is how you fix it. Instead of making a new `DataTable` every single time you pass you make one outside of the loop and pass in the same table every time. `TableAdapter` does not clear out the table before it fills by default.

```
private YourFunction(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         // read item
         url_given = row["url_String"].ToString();

         String qrystring = "select url_String,word,count from wordcount where url_String='" + url_given + "' and word in (select * from temp) ";
         db.searchandorder(qrystring, dt1);
         // searchandorder is a call to a function that establishes the db connections and passes the query to the data adapter.
     }

    DoSomthingWithResults(dt1);
}

public void searchandorder (String sql, DataTable dt)
{
    conn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill( dt);


    conn.Close();
    Console.Write("table coloumns" + dt.Columns.ToString());

    return dt;
}
```

Now, that is the bare minimum to make your program work. There are a LOT of other bad practices you are doing.

- Don't reuse a connection: Your `conn` object should be created inside `searchandorder` and be inside a `using` statement. Don't worry about making "too many connection", .NET will use [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) and reuse old connections.
- Use `using` statments: Anything that implements IDisposable should be in a `using` statement (unless the item is being returned)
- Follow naming standards: There is a [set of standards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx) C# code follows, your class `searcandhorder` should be named `SerchAndOrder`.
- Use Parameters: You are vulnerable to a [SQL injection attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon) use parameters for your data adapters. Not only does it improve safety, it makes your program faster by allowing SQL server to cache the query execution plan.

Here is a version of your program with those fixes applied.

```
private YourFunction(DataTable dt)
{
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         // read item
         url_given = row["url_String"].ToString();
         var parameter = new SqlParameter("@urlGiven", SqlDbType.VarChar, url_given.Length);
         parameter.Value = url_given;

         String qrystring = "select url_String,word,count from wordcount where url_String=@urlGiven and word in (select * from temp) ";
         db.searchandorder(qrystring, dt1, parameter);
         // searchandorder is a call to a function that establishes the db connections and passes the query to the data adapter.
     }

    DoSomthingWithResults(dt1);
}

public void SearchAndOrder (String sql, DataTable dt, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
    {
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    Console.Write("table coloumns" + dt.Columns.ToString());

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Here is a sample of the row in wordcount    url then word then its count  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx   TechCenter 1

Comment: I belevie you copy pasted the wrong link, that takes me to the Microsoft SQL Server base page.

Comment: this was to explain the format of my table  "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545450.aspx" Microsoft 21            i.e a url     word   count

Comment: Now I understand what you ment.

Comment: I have added the implementation of my searchand order function. I understand what you mean by replacing the datatable so Im rewriting the function but still dont get if I need to fill the datatable through the data adapter in the loop or outside